# Running Netbeans platform application without a GUI

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

My Java application built using Netbeans platform application. I need to run my application without a GUI.
Anyone knows a way to run Netbeans platform application without a GUI ?

Comment: Have you checked http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqNonGuiPlatformApp ?

Comment: Thanks. In this case it needs to maintain two code bases. One is to running GUI (without removing clusters) and other one is for non GUI (Remove clusters from the platform). I need to use same code base.

Comment: That's at the top of the page. Did even the " Note that this explains how to develop an application which is only ever meant to run headless, not how to develop a single application which can run in either GUI or command line mode (which is described in the second half of this page)." and "How Can I Make My NetBeans Platform Run in GUI or Command-Line Mode?" sections not help? It's hard to understand what issues you are having running in non-GUI mode.

Comment: The problem is some users need the GUI and others are not. I cannot remove these platform clusters runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information gathered largely from [How Can I Make My NetBeans Platform Run in GUI or Command-Line Mode?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqNonGuiPlatformApp) :

- you will typically need to add a module to interpret some custom command-line arguments using the [Command Line Processing API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-sendopts/)
- Remember that you should not use System.out, System.err and System.in for the output, error and input streams in the options processor but instead get them from the Env object passed as a parameter to the process method.
- When running a platform application which contains the Window System and other GUI modules, you will also need to specify `--nosplash --nogui` on the command line at startup to prevent the splash screen and window system from being displayed.

Comment: --nogui is done for me. It really helped me to run my application without a GUI. Thanks lot.

Comment: Great, if this answer is correct, don't forget to accept it by clicking the tick.